# Print/Debug.Log is not showing output on Unity Console

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, console

I am trying to print a simple statement using C# on Unity Console but i don't know why it is not printing.
[image]

Comment: 1.or else create a c# script file here in the project window [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPAPR.png)
2. just drag the script file and add to ur object this worked for me

Answer (score 30, accepted):

*If print does **not** work, `Debug.Log` will **not** work either so that's **not** the problem.*

**These are the possible reasons why `print` is not showing in the console:**

**1**.Script is **not** attached to a GameObject.

[image]

**2**.The GameObject the script is attached to is **not** Active. Activate it from the Editor.

[image]
**3**.The `NumberWizard` script is **not** enabled. Enable the script.

[image]

**4**.The log toggle is **not** checked.

[image]

From your screenshot, both Debug, Warning and Error messages are enabled, so we can exclude what's in 4.

Comment: You Are life savior.. The third one works . God bless you

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I had to delete the script I created and used the add component to create a new script.

Comment: I'm in build `2019.2.17f1` on Win10 Pro and saw that my log toggle (in your step 4) was accumulating messages as the number indicating how many messages are present was increasing, but they were not actually displaying in the console. The same messages would successfully display in my custom in-game console. Restarting Unity fixed the issue. I might report this as a bug to Unity later if I have time, but just an FYI for posterity

Answer (score 5):

### Pressing "Play"

According to this [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/25269/how-do-i-write-to-the-console.html), `print()` or `Debug.Log`, only will work with the following conditions

> It seems that the key piece of information I was missing was that
>   Debug.Log writes to the console only when you run the game from within
>   unity by pressing the "play" button above the game view.
>
> I was running my game by pressing Ctrl-B, or pressing "Build & Run" in
>   the Build Settings window. In that case, it will only output to the
>   log file

So you have to hit the **play** button above the game view, not by using the "Build & Run".

---

### Check your filters

According to this [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/563309/i-cant-get-debuglog-to-work-at-all.html), you should also check your filters
[image]

Comment: No. This is Unity3D

Comment: System.Console.WriteLine("your string here");  is also not working @Svek

Comment: and i am pressing Play button.Nothing Happens

Comment: @Programmer solution works... script is not attached to the object

Comment: Which log file? Player.log? Can't find it there either

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Debug.Log`? Also, you can also use these for specificity: `Debug.LogWarning` and `Debug.LogError`. Also, make sure this script is attached.

E.g. `Debug.Log("Started");`

Hope it helps!

Comment: If print and Debug.Log don't work, probably, your code isn't getting called.

Comment: Debug.Log and Print both are not printing on Console.
   @mindOfAi

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint on your `Start()` method? Make sure it's getting called.

Comment: Programmer solution works... script is not attached to the object

Comment: Yeah, I stated it in my answer that you should make sure the script's attached.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check that your Script are not attached to the object assuming everything is installed to build (.NET SDK, C# extension and MonoProject).

- Click object as shown "Hierarchy" panel on the left and choose one of objects.
- Click "Add Component" at the left bottom panel. Choose scripts and add your script file
- Then add your debug message to code, i.e. `Debug.Log("here is my debug message..");` and Run again.

[image]