# Debug.Log() not displaying anything

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

*Summary*

---

Trying to set up the base for a mechanic, just trying to get it to actually trigger after x amount of time has passed. At the moment, I'm using `Debug.Log()` to make it obvious if y event has triggered. This prints nothing to console, which is a problem. Basically, I'm trying to set up a cripple mechanic so when the time passes, a negative effect is applied to the character if they don't do something to avoid it.

*Research*

---

[Print/Debug.Log is not showing output on Unity Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338376/print-debug-log-is-not-showing-output-on-unity-console/42338612)

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html

*Question*

---

What in the world is happening? I've made sure all the problems that I'm aware may cause issues aren't the case. Unfortunately, these issues don't seem to be the case. So any ideas? Code's below. Sorry for copying the full thing, but I can't pin point where the problem is coming from.

*Code*

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Cripple:MonoBehaviour
{
    public int EffectMagnitude;
    public string EffectType;
    public int TimeForIncrease;

    private void Start()
    {
        EffectStart();
    }

    private void Update()
    {

    }


    IEnumerator EffectStart()
    {
        int CounterCripple = 0;
        do
        {
            Debug.Log("Has run: " + CounterCripple);
            if (CounterCripple >= TimeForIncrease && CounterCripple < TimeForIncrease * 2)
            {
                if (EffectType == "Hunger")
                {
                    Debug.Log("<color=blue> Hunger effect triggered</color><color=green> Tier One</color>");
                }

                else if (EffectType == "Restless")
                {
                    Debug.Log("<color=blue> Restless effect triggered</color><color=green> Tier One</color>");
                }

                else if (EffectType == "Thirst")
                {
                    Debug.Log("<color=blue> Thirst effect triggered:</color><color=green> Tier One</color>");
                }
            }

            else if (CounterCripple >= TimeForIncrease * 2 && CounterCripple < TimeForIncrease * 3)
            {
                if (EffectType == "Hunger")
                {
                    Debug.Log("<color=blue> Hunger effect triggered</color><color=orange> Tier Two</color>");
                }

                else if (EffectType == "Restless")
                {
                    Debug.Log("<color=blue> Restless effect triggered</color><color=orange> Tier Two</color>");
                }

                else if (EffectType == "Thirst")
                {
                    Debug.Log("<color=blue> Thirst effect triggered:</color><color=orange> Tier Two</color>");
                }
            }

            else if (CounterCripple >= TimeForIncrease * 3)
            {
                if (EffectType == "Hunger")
                {
                    Debug.Log("<color=blue> Hunger effect triggered</color><color=red> Tier Three</color>");
                }

                else if (EffectType == "Restless")
                {
                    Debug.Log("<color=blue> Restless effect triggered</color><color=red> Tier Three</color>");
                }

                else if (EffectType == "Thirst")
                {
                    Debug.Log("<color=blue> Thirst effect triggered:</color><color=red> Tier Three</color>");
                }
            }
            CounterCripple++;
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
        } while (true);
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried `StartCoroutine(EffectStart())` instead of only `EffectStart()` in `Start()`?

Comment: Why did that help? Not meaning that as a rude statement, I'm just curious. I've not used this before, but the timer was needed so yeah.

Comment: I'll put it in an answer so this question can be closed

Comment: Thank you for doing so, this has been doing my head in for a week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `StartCoroutine(EffectStart())` instead of only `EffectStart()`.

It seemed to me that this function you were trying to call was a `Coroutine`. Quoting from Unity's documentation which can be found here: [Unity's Coroutine Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

"*To set a coroutine running, you **need** to use the StartCoroutine function*"

Comment: This quote can be found in the paragraph immediately after the second code block on that page in the link. There are some really useful examples as well

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. I will make sure to be more thorough in future.

Comment: Anytime, be sure to accept the answer if it solved the problem